# jquery load() is duplicating div layer instead of re-populating the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

as the title says, having a bit of a problem on a page thats using jquery's load function.

if you click the 'about' icon on the page it use the jquery load function, here's a demo of whats going wrong http://goo.gl/CaQqy1

you can see the #homepage-slider bugging out by displaying a div inside a div with the same id's so it duplicates the backgrounds.

here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#nav-icons a').click(function(){                
        jQuery('#nav-icons a').removeClass("active-icon");
        jQuery(this).addClass( "active-icon" );

        var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #main-content';
        var toLoadSlider = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #homepage-slider';

        jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').hide('fast',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            jQuery('#homepage-slider').empty().load(toLoadSlider) 
            jQuery('#main-content').empty().load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()) 

        }
        function showNewContent() {
            jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').show('normal');
        } 

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a side note: You need to pass function reference not to call  method. So use `.load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)`

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle out of it - your website will be repaired based on answers and the link to your page will be useless to understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that to use load(), the pages you pull in  must be on the same domain so I'm not sure how to get that working on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround for this issue by removing the id and class on the div layers

```
function showNewContent() {
                jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').show('normal').removeAttr('id class');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `unwrap()` to remove the duplicated parent element:

```
function showNewContent() {
    jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').show('normal').unwrap();
}
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Or add a wrapper div inside your content and load that, for example:

```
var toLoadSlider = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #homepage-slider .wrapper';
```